# What is the term for E[x*y']

Tags: stochastic-processes, descriptive-statistics, vector-fields

I know this is probably a very simple question, but I recall learning that for 2 random vectors, x & y,  with mean mx & my,

E[(x-mx)*(y-my)'] is the covariance  &
E[x*y'] is the correlation

However, according to wikipedia, the correlation is actually: 
E[(x-mx)*(y-my)']/(std(x)*std(y))

Thus, what is the correct term for: E[x*y']   (if such a term exists)

Thanks!

Comment: The answers below are right, but I've also seen that alternative definition of "correlation" as $E[x y']$ in some areas (signal processing?).

Comment: @leon The alternative is correct when both $x$ and $y$ have unit ($L^2$) norms. It is equivalent to the Wikipedia formula then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, after further research, I realized that there are indeed 2 definitions, depending on the field.

In statistics, the correlation is defined as: 
 $\frac{E[ (x-\mu_x)(y-\mu_y)^T]}{\sigma_x\sigma_y}$

In signal processing & random processes, correlation ussually means:
$E[x'y]$

As pointed out, the above quantity in statistics is refered to as the 'joint moment' or 'mixed moment'

Source: wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation

Answer (score 4):

$\mathbb{E}(XY)$ is known as a *joint moment* or *mixed moment* of $X$ and $Y$.

The equivalent *central moment* $\mathbb{E}\big((X-\mu_X)(Y-\mu_Y)\big)$ is the covariance. This will be the same as $\mathbb{E}(XY)$ if the variables have been centered so that $\mu_X = \mu_Y = 0$.

The correlation of two variables is their covariance divided by the product of their standard deviations. If the variables have unit variance, so $\sigma_X = \sigma_Y = 1$, then their covariance is the same as their correlation.

If the variables have been standardised so they have mean zero and standard deviation one, then $\mathbb{E}(XY)$ is a simple formula for the correlation. This is one of the advantages of standardising your variables, if possible, before trying to prove something about their correlation.

Answer (score 3):

The definition from wikipedia is correct. For $n$ dimensional random column vectors $x$ and $y$, the covariance matrix is n times n and it's $E[ (x-\mu_x)(y-\mu_y)^T ]$. If the means are zero, this equals $E[ xy^T ]$ and if the standard deviations are 1, this is also the correlation.

In my experience, $E[ xy^T ]$ is usually of interest only because it is the covariance, ie because at least one mean is zero.

Comment: so there is no specific name for it?

Comment: When it is not the covariance, no, not as far as I know.